# Validate Form Data After Redirect to Index (Instead of Show)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In Rails, I'm attempting to validate form data and if valid, redirect to the index page for that class instead of it's show page. I've set this up as follows:

**In the model:**

```
validates :name, :description, :link, presence:true
```

**In the controller:**

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  respond_with(@product)
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.save
  @products = Product.all
  render action: "index"
end
```

The problem I'm having is that while the validation does prevent the product from being made, it still redirects to the index page instead of displaying the errors on the new page. I'm guessing I need to add an if statement to the controller to only render index if the form is valid, but I'm not sure what that statement would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create` action should look like:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  if @product.save
    @products = Product.all
    render action: "index"
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```